# links break when containing element positioned

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, css-position

I have an unordered list of links like so:

```
<ul id="linkwrapper">
    <li><a name="latestBlog"class="menuLinks"id="link1"href="#latestBlog"><img src="images/blog.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a name="meetings"class="menuLinks suckit"id="link2"href="#meetings"><img src="images/meetings.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a name="aboutus"class="menuLinks suckit"id="link3"href="#aboutus"><img src="images/who_we_are.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a name="contact"class="menuLinks"id="link4"href="#contact"><img src="images/contact.png" ,></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the following javascript to cancel regular link behavior and display a different div depending on which link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').hide(); // Hide All Content Divs

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link1').trigger('click');
});

$('#linkwrapper a').click(function(){
    var $contentDiv = $("#" + this.id + "content");

        $allContentDivs.hide(); // Hide All Divs
        $contentDiv.show(); // Show Div


    return false;        
});
});

</script>
```

This works great, until I start positioning the unordered list. When I do this much css it still works fine:

```
#linkwrapper {
position:absolute;
left:175px;
}
```

but if I add another line like so...

```
#linkwrapper {
position:absolute;
left:175px;
top:0px;
}
```

...only the last link in the  is clickable. why does that one line of css break the menu?

Comment: css doesn't break any functionality you can check it in the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h73ah/

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the closing tag on the last link's image: `/>` instead of `,>`
2. `$(document).ready` inside `$(document).ready` looks weird, you should better move `$('#link1').trigger('click');` to the end.
3. Everything works fine, or the problem is out of what you have described. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/fVE4m/